# Print hexadecimal code from int into string

Tags: c#, string, hex

I need to save a `string` with the `hexadecimal code` of an `int`.

For example the `hexadecimal` value for the `int 15` is `xoooF`.

My problem is that I have to save this code in a `string` like this:

```
int myint = myStringLength; //this value might change
string myIntExhCode = myint.convertThisIntoMyCode();

//and the string has to be exactly "/xoooF"
```

So in this question I have two problmes:

- The first is how to automatically convert an `int` into the `hexadecimal` code like `15 = xoooF`
- The second is how to create a string containing `\xoooF` because any try of concatenating strings like this resulted into a `\\xoooF` and this is not correct since in output I need the `string` to be converted into the `ascii code`.

How can I achieve those two tasks?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `000F == 15.ToString("X4")`

Comment: Do you want `o`s or `0`s? Because the hexadecimal value of `15` is `000F`, not `oooF`.

Comment: Do you mean forward slash or backslash? It seems likely that you actually mean the backward slash rather than the forward slash -- in which case the debugger will display a single backslash escaped with another backslash, making it look like there is two. It is really only a single backslash, though.

Comment: backslash are the correct ones, I fixed if. thanks. So if I print a string which is \x000F and the debugger shows the double backslash I will see the ascii code anyway?

Comment: It's very unclear what you mean by "a string which is \x000F". If you mean the equivalent of `string x = "\x000F"` then you need to learn about the differences between what's *in* a string, and a string *literal* representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is quite vague. If you want *hexadecimal* format, but with `0` (digit zero) changed into `o` (small latin letter `o`) you can implement, say, an *extension method* (in order to keep your proposed code intact):

```
 public static partial class IntExtensions {
   public static string convertThisIntoMyCode(this int value) {
     return "\\x" + value.ToString("X4").Replace('0', 'o'); // or "/x" + ... 
   }
 }
```

...

```
 int myint = myStringLength; //this value might change
 string myIntExhCode = myint.convertThisIntoMyCode();

 // Test output
 Console.Write(myIntExhCode);
```

Comment: Do you use a `partial class` for extension methods?

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen: I often use `partial class` for the extension methods esp. on *popular* types (like `int`) when we might expect that there're/wiil be another set of extensions

Comment: That is interesting. When another set of extensions are needed, you could also simply create a separate (non-partial) class for them. I see no problem with that. The different classes for extensions to `int` could be in different namespaces, if desired. If you want the same namespace, you just use different class names.

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen: you're quite right, if the name conflict (we tend to use `SomeType + "Extensions"` name for the class which holds `SomeType` extension methods) appears it can easily be solved. Different `namespace`s will help. However, `partial class` nips the (possible) problem in the bud and it doesn't add any overhead - that's why I use it.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
int i = 15;
string result = "\\x" + i.ToString("X").PadLeft(4, 'o');
```

Comment: I tried the `"/x + string` formula, but the result that came out was `"//xooF"`. Is there a way to remove the double / from the string?

Comment: I very much doubt that it came out as `//xooF`, as forward slashes aren't escaped at all. I doubt that forward slashes are what's required anyway though...

Comment: @JonSkeet my fault I just copied the _the string has to be exactly "/xoooF"_ from OP

Comment: Sure - but my point is that the OP wouldn't actually see `//xoooF` as claimed. They must already be converting the forward slash to backslash themselves. Between that and the o vs 0 difference, it's a bit of a weird and imprecise question.

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley in case of `16` do you expect the result `/xoo10` or `/xoo1o`

Comment: Yeah it's a bit confusing because I'm confused myself about what it has been asked to me, btw in case of 16 it would be /xoo10, thanks for pointing me this case

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley so  `Replace('0', 'o')` will return a invalid result. Maybe you shoudl also handle the case, if your integer doesn't fit into 4 hexadecimal digits